# Can two solids form in a double displacement reaction?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I am trying to react silver flouride with magnesium chloride. I know it is a double displacement reaction but so far the equation I have gotten is:

$$\ce{2AgF (aq) + MgCl2 (aq) -> MgF2 (s) + 2AgCl (s)}$$

Is this possible or am I doing something wrong? If my equation is correct would this mean that there is no reaction? I'm supposed to find the complete ionic equation and the net ionic equation but I'm not getting either with the above balanced equation. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This is surely possible, though uncommon; [lithopone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithopone#Production) is a more widely known example. Also, welcome to Chem.SE, and pay attention to the formatting.

Comment: States of aggregation should not be subscripted, it is not wrong, but the [recommendations (Sec. 2.1.)](https://web.archive.org/web/20131125004444/http://pac.iupac.org/publications/pac/pdf/1982/pdf/5406x1239.pdf) are different.